# Vue PWA how to change service-worker base url

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Let's say I have a root or base url of `aws.com/prefix/`. I want to run the PWA (`vue init pwa my-vue-app`) at this url, but the PWA by default serves at `/`. I was able to change the assets path in various configurations for css, js, and the index.html, but the `service-worker.js` file in `dist` seems to only load at `/`.

Is there a parameter somewhere to allow a different base or root url for service-worker in the Vue / Vuex PWA project?

The available config files that might have options for this are:

```
build/service-worker-prod.js
build/webpack.base.conf.js
build/webpack.prod.conf.js
config/index.js
```

Comment: I changed the following line in `build/service-worker-prod.js`, `navigator.serviceWorker.register('PREFIX_HERE/service-worker.js')`

To fix the issue, but this seems a bit hacky, wondering if there is a proper configuration location to change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add a  element to the index.html such as:

```
<base href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.publicPath %>">
```

Then it will use the webpack publicPath, which is a redirect to the index.js assetsPath value.

The service-worker will adopt this base path.